# How to calculate and store the times of a regularly scheduled bidaily event for the next few days?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

On one of my sites, I need to offer the users a way to select 11am and 4pm time slots for several days (including today) in the future, with a total of 8 options.  Of course, if it's already past 11am or 4pm today, then I shouldn't show them expired options.

So, for example, if it's currently noon on the 28th of February, then I would need to show the user the following 8 options:

```
28-Feb-13 at 4pm 
01-Mar-13 at 11am 
01-Mar-13 at 4pm 
02-Mar-13 at 11am 
02-Mar-13 at 4pm 
03-Mar-13 at 11am 
03-Mar-13 at 4pm 
04-Mar-13 at 11am
```

Also, I would need a way to store those options in MySQL so that I would now which date/time they selected and save it to the DB together with their registration info.

This sounds easy to explain in words, but I'm having an incredibly difficult time figuring out how to program this in PHP.

How would I do this using the `DateTime()` class?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the gist of it

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$num_options = 8;
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++)
{
    echo $datetime->format("d-M-y \a\\t ga") . "<br>";
    $datetime->modify("+12 hours");
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NwQ514)